# Python-конвертация строк pandas в список

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица в pandas, каждую строку которой нужно перевести в отдельный список (независимо от числа строк в таблице). Конечный результат должен быть  таким:  [1,2,3] [10,20,30] Текущий вариант выводит что-то непонятное...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#создаем таблицу
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,10], 'var2': [2,20],'var3':[3,30]})
#определение количества строк
row_n=df.shape[0]
# перевод в список в таблице
for i in df.iloc[1:row_n]:
    y=list(i)
    print(y)
```

Comment: Вы не хотите читать документацию?

Answer (score 2):

Как и в предыдущем вашем вопросе, все решается просто и векторизиванно.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,10], 'var2': [2,20],'var3':[3,30]})
res = df.values
print(res)
```

res:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [10 20 30]]
```

Вам нужно начать читать документацию.

Comment: Документацию я читал и сам пробовал. Я на форум сразу никогда не пишу.

Comment: И потом на выходе получаются вложенные списки. Можно ли сделать чтобы сразу получались отдельные списки?

Comment: отдельные списки? Новый столбец в фрейме, со списком для каждой строки?

Answer (score 0):

> Вот такой вариант получился. Мне пока нравится :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,10], 'var2': [2,20],'var3':[3,30]})
for i in range(2):
    res=list(df.iloc[i])
    print(res)
```